# DTDevice and DTDeviceBase private framework use

Tags: iphone, ios, macos

I am trying to install app on device through private frameworks provided by xcode located at

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/
```

path.There are two frameworks

```
DTDeviceKit
DTDeviceKitBase
```

These are also used by "iPhone Configuration Utility". I want the main header files of these framework.
I tried

```
#import <DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit.h>
```

but I get compiler error because the DTDeviceKit.h is not found.
I set the

```
library search path="$(DEVELOPER_DIR)/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks"

other linker flag=-framework DTDeviceKit -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks
```

options. 
Anyone has done anything like this? or 
Is there any way to know the header files inside a framework?

Answer (score 1):

As header files for private frameworks are not included in the SDK, you will need to reverse eningeer header files from the binary. [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) is a nice utlity that helps a lot here :